# Generics wildcard confusion

Tags: java, generics

What is the functional difference between

```
Container<Class>
```

and

```
Container<? extends Class>
```

?

Anything that inherits from `Class` is a `Class` so I don't understand why bother with `?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class is `final`, the `<? extends Class>` will be applicable only for the `Class` type.

Therefore, there's no functional difference between `Container<Class>` and `Container<? extends Class>`.

**Update**: If your question refers to *What is a wildcard ?* and if we assume we're not talking about `Class`, but some other (extendable) type, here's the difference:

Let's say we have two classes:

- `class Shape`
- `class Rectangle extends Shape`

Consider the following method signature:

```
public void addRectangle(List<? extends Shape> shapes)
```

This is an example of *bounded wildcard*, where the `Shape` part is called `upper bound`.

```
public void addRectangle(List<? extends Shape> shapes) {
    // Compile-time error!
    shapes.add(0, new Rectangle());
}
```

The reason for the compile-time error is that the type of the second parameter to `shapes.add()` is `? extends Shape`, which in human language means ***an unknown subtype of Shape***. Since we don't know what type it is, we don't know if it is a supertype of `Rectangle`. It might or might not be such a supertype, so it isn't safe to pass a `Rectangle` there.

The example is taken from:

- [The Java Tutorials - Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: assume class is not final, what then?
If Something inherits form Class couldn't it still be in Container<Class>?